# Can't uninstall or repair Bluetooth driver on Dell Latitude E6540

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Dell Latitude E6540, Windows 7 Pro SP1; installed programs list includes "Intel(R) PROSet/Wireless Software for Bluetooth(R) Technology". If I right-click on that in Control Panel / Programs and Features, I get options for "Change" and "Repair". If I choose "Repair", it operates for a couple of minutes, then tells me that "Bluetooth Device Monitor failed to start"; it suggests I ensure that I have sufficient privilege to start system services (which I do; I run out of an admin account all the time on this machine). It then notifies me it is "backing out" of the installation, and informs me that it did not complete successfully.

If I select the option for "Repair", it asks me if I want this program to make changes to the computer, I select yes, it operates for a while and then gives the same message.

If I go to Services and attempt to start the Bluetooth monitor manually, it says that it failed to respond in a timely manner.

I tried running a Dell install of a Bluetooth driver set; it failed, saying (in its log file) that it found an existing product.

When I attempt to use my Bluetooth headset, it pairs and shows up under Bluetooth devices, but I don't get Audio on it.

Is there some way I can get rid of the non-working Bluetooth driver on my machine and install a working one?

---

Based on the answer I received, I attempted to uninstall the BT drivers through device manager; they disappeared from the list in Device Manager, but the install program still failed the same way.

There were two items listed under Bluetooth in Device Manager, the Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator and the Generic Bluetooth Adapter.  I got properties and device details for both of those, together they listed 4 files (1 in Windows\system32\drivers and one in \windows\system32. After claiming ownership of them, changing their permissions, and deleting them, I ran the installer again, and got the same result. I went back and again removed the items from Device Manager (where they had showed back up); installation again produced the same result.

I looked at the installation log, and the message I get is:

```
Found existing product version: 2.6.1212.0302
MUP Package contains version: 19.0.1601.0594
Execute: setup.exe  
Error: setup.exe exited with return code: 1603
MUP finished: Thu Aug 11 11:53:13 2016

Exiting with Return Code: 1603
```

I think 2.6 is the version that I've been trying to get rid of - I remember seeing it on one of the driver descriptions or something. So it looks like there is still something there from that older installation that my installation cannot overwrite.

I've also noticed that there are other files in System32\drivers named "bt*.sys", and their detail information identifies at least some of them as being part of a bluetooth installation. Do I have to go through the ownership/permission/delete sequence with all of them? If so, is there somewhere I can get a list?

Thanks for your help thus far -- am heading to a search page for driver cleaner to see what I can find there.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can go to device manager, find your Bluetooth, click right mouse button and next click uninstall but i think driver will install again automatically, but You should try.

   2. Also, You can go to device manager, find your Bluetooth, click right mouse button -> properties -> driver -> driver details. You should descry  path for example C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\Nrtwsfw02.dat or .sys.(You have to remove driver's from all path, which you see) Go to your patch witch this drivers and delete this manually, after that, you can go to step one again and now drivers will be uninstall permanently.
   3. If still it dosnt work try program like Driver Cleaner 3.3.

      - If removal succeeds, you can install new drivers fallow this steps:
      - You can download this [Driver Pack](https://drp.su/index.htm)
      - offline version
      - install drivers using offline
        driver pack
      - **but stay focus and care on unsolicited programs like chrome in

        Russian language !!!**

Comment: For number 1.   it will only install automatically again, if you failed to check the box to remove the driver from your computer, on the window that appears when you click uninstall driver from the device manager window.

Comment: Yes, Driver will be install automatically again. Always worth a try.
I think number 2 should work but we will see.